# JavaScript loop does not accept a variable in the condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a web application that is able to export a list of names (sorted by a value) that are selected before. Everything works except that my variable does not work in one of the for-loops.

I already tried altering my code a bunch. Tried to replace the variable with a lot of things, like structuring the array in other ways, trying to get the number I am looking for with the `return` of  `getExportCount()` which was not working aswell.

In short words:

This works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (wstv[i].toExport == true) {
            console.log(wstv[i]);
            exportList.push(wstv[i]);
        }
    }
```

This does not:

```
for (var i = 0; i < exportNum; i++) {
        if (wstv[i].toExport == true) {
            console.log(wstv[i]);
            exportList.push(wstv[i]);
        }
    }
```

The complete(ish) code is seen below:

```
var exportNum;

function getExportCount() {
    var toExportCount = -1;
    for (var k = 0; k < wstv.length; k++) {
        if (wstv[k].toExport == true) {
            toExportCount += 1;
        }
    }
    toExportCount = exportNum;
}

function exporter() {
    getExportCount();
    var exportList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < exportNum; i++) {
        if (wstv[i].toExport == true) {
            exportList.push(wstv[i]);
        }
    }

    var exportListSort = exportList.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value
    });

    for (var j = 0; j < exportList.length; j++) {
        if (exportListSort[j] != undefined) {
            $("body").append("<p>" + exportListSort[j].longName + "</p>")
        } else {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    }
    return "Export successfull"
}
```

The "working" example (from above) can be found on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luigithefrench/38s4r0u2/). I want my code to do the exact same thing as now but with the variable instead of the "3".

Could someone please tell me what am I overlooking here?

EDIT:
First of all thank you for all the help!
As pointed out in the comments I changed my logic to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wstv.length; i++) {
        if (wstv[i].toExport == true) {
            console.log(wstv[i]);
            exportList.push(wstv[i]);
        } else {
            console.log("Error on export Array");
        }
    }
```

I also updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luigithefrench/38s4r0u2/29/) to a real working version.

Comment: where do you assign a value to `exportNum`? In your snippet it will always be `undefined`

Comment: It is `target = source;` ... just saying ...

Comment: Your logic is very strange also, suppose you fix the commented mistake. Why you first count how much elements are available to export (this counter is also wrong since you start with a `-1`), and then traverse the first `N` elements of the array where `N` equals the number of elements available to export. What would happen if you have `2` elements available to export, but they are not on the position `1` neither on the position `2` of the array.

Comment: Please take all of these comments into account, and fix up your code so that it could possibly work.  One suggestion I'd add is to ditch the global variable `exportNum` and have `getExportCount` return that value instead.  Clueing us in as to the exact contents of `wstv` would be helpful too.

Comment: First of all thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

You never assign `exportNum` to a value. I'm guessing you swapped variables in your `getExportCount` function, and that the last line should be :

```
exportNum = toExportCount;
```

It would be cleaner to assign this value to a local variable in `exporter` and not use a global varibale though, you'll avoid errors when another function changes it

Comment: @melpomene yeah mb, idk probably should be sleeping sry, I deleted those. Thx for pointing out